# I'm creating a survey using ASP.NET...but how to I create the database to store it?

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2012, survey

I've created the survey form but I don't know how to continue doing the database...
Can someone each me?
Anyway, Here's my code:

```
<tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">5) Would you share our website to your friends?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">6) Any comments or suggestions?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment" runat="server" Height="182px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="271px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="button" onclick="btnSubmit_Click()" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" OnClick="btnReset_Click" Text="Reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
```

As you noticed, I used radiobuttonlist and comment box. These are the reasons why I'm having problem to create the database... Please teach me...I only know how to create tables for database...

And the database might be something like this...

This is the QUESTION Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Question] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
    [Options] NCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

This is the ANSWERS Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [QuestionId] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
    [Answers] NCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

And I'm also not sure about the NCHAR(10) ... 
So this is how bad I am in programming.
Please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have experience with SQL, you could try [parse.com](https://parse.com/), just to get something up and running quick.

You'll have to read through their docs, they also have tutorials and a quickstart explanation.

I would still recommend learning about SQL, simply because you don't really need to know that much to get going.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use database servers like sql or ms-sql or oracle or other database engines unless u are asking query to create the database, which i assume not, as there is no query or other related tags in your question

Comment: Well you need to install one of the instances of those database engine in your computer. create a database in that database engine. and use a connection string to connect to the database that you have for your code to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a `SQL Server` (`SQLExpress`, `LocalDB`, Full `MSSQL`) and you are able to make use of `EF` ([Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx)), then you can use `Code First` to build your `Database` from your `domain models`.

[EF Code First Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

Assuming you're running Windows, `SQLExpress` and `LocalDB` should already be installed on your PC, if not they can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062).  Either of these will suffice for what you are looking to do and both are free.  You could alternatively pay for a fully featured `MSSQL` license, however, this might be overkill for you currently.

All of these will happily run on your local machine, if however you are looking to deploy your application to the Internet, you may want to considering some sort of hosting option unless you are comfortable with doing so yourself.